# How to rebase a program in Ghidra

Tags: reverse-engineering, offset, ghidra

I need to calculate certain offsets of symbols inside a given binary.
Finding the symbols is done using a RE tool such as Ghidra.
However, the tool sets the addresses according to the `Image Base` parameter in the header of the binary (Elf/PE/etc.)

How do rellocate the binary to address 0 in Ghidra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following parameter to `0`:

Window -> Memory map -> Set Image Base (house icon)